# How to post data to a server with jquery, ajax and asp.net mvc5 without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I understand the very BASICs of posting to the server with http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp but I fail to see how to use it in asp.net mvc. Please could somebody give a very basic demonstration.

e.g. (second example on link)

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
  txt=$("input").val();
  $.post("demo_ajax_gethint.asp",{suggest:txt},function(result){
    $("span").html(result);
  });
});
```

So when the keyup is pressed is clicked it sends a post request to "demo_ajax_gethint.asp" with the data variable "txt" and on callback it changes the span object html to the data sent back... correct?

My question is, how do I define the function in "demo_ajax_gethint.asp"? I am used to controller / models / views and this confuses me!

Many thanks as always

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/ - nuff said.

Comment: If you're using asp.net MVC, you will not be putting in the extension to post to, it should just be the controller/actionResult you are sending your post to.  demp/demo_ajax_getint for example.